# Canonical coresolutions of cosheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $M$ be a sufficiently nice topological space (e.g. smooth manifold).

Recall that a (pre-)cosheaf in a category $\mathcal{C}$ over a topological space $M$ is essentially a $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$-valued (pre-)sheaf. In the category of modules, a more hands-on definition in terms of open covers of $M$ can be given, to be looked up, for example, in ["Cosheaves and Homology" by Bredon](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-25/issue-1/Cosheaves-and-homology/pjm/1102986387.full). Morphisms of (pre-)cosheaves are natural transformations of the functors defining the (pre-)cosheaves.

In the following, consider all (pre-)cosheaves to live in the category of abelian groups. Some definitions from Bredon's article:

- A (pre-)cosheaf $P$ is called *flabby* if all precosheaf maps $P(U) \to P(V)$ for open $U \subset V \subset M$ are injective.
- A precosheaf $P$ over $M$ is *locally zero* if for all $x \in M$ and every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is some open neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $x$ so that the precosheaf map $P(V) \to P(U)$ is zero.
- A sequence $F \stackrel{f}{\to} G \stackrel{g}{\to} H$ of precosheaves over $M$ is *locally exact* if $g \circ f = 0$ and the precosheaf $U \mapsto \ker g(U)/\mathrm{im} f(U)$ is locally zero.
- A *coresolution* of a cosheaf $C$ is a locally exact sequence of cosheaves
  $$\dots \to C_2 \to C_1 \to C_0 \to C \to 0,$$
  and the coresolution is called *flabby* if $C_0,C_1,C_2,\dots$ are flabby cosheaves.

**Question:** Are there any assumptions for a cosheaf $C$ so that there exists a canonical coresolution for  $C$, similarly to the Godement resolution of sheaves? Are there counterexamples to the existence of such coresolutions?

---

Maybe this question is not so easy: the main textbook on cosheaves appears to be Bredon's work, and there, flabby coresolutions are constructed, but only for the constant cosheaf on suitably nice spaces. The textbook is quite difficult to get through for me, so I miss the details, but I imagine this restriction happens for a reason. And clearly, just naively dualizing the Godement resolution into the cosheaf setting will not do you much good: Costalks of cosheaves are, in most interesting examples, completely trivial, for example for the cosheaf of compactly supported continuous functions on $M$.